# How to remove method from a type in C# with Cecil?

Tags: c#, mono.cecil

I have an assembly that contains a type named `EncryptedStrings`, and inside it is a method called `DecryptString`. I wanted to remove this method from the type and write the modified assembly back. I wrote this very simple code for it:

```
var file = @"path-to-file.exe";

// load assembly
var ass = AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly(file);

// find the type
var type = ass.MainModule.GetType("EncryptedStrings");

// find the method in the type
var method = type.Methods.First(meth => meth.Name == "DecryptString");

// remove the method
type.Methods.Remove(method);

// write assembly back
ass.Write("fixed.exe");
```

However, when I run this code, I get an exception saying:

> System.ArgumentException: Member 'System.String DecryptString(System.String)' is declared in another module and needs to be imported

I have no idea what it wants from me... The method IS defined in that module, so what am I supposed to import?

What should I do to fix this and delete the method from the type?

Comment: What do you mean by "remove the method"? An assembly can´t be changed once compiled. What exactly do you want to achieve *actually*? Sounds like an XY-problem. Why do you think you need this?

Comment: I mean to use Cecil to edit the compiled assembly and delete the method from the type (it is not used anywhere)

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: I am trying to deobfuscate a C# library, I wanted to test out removing methods on a simple example, so that I could use the same code to remove methods and types that are there just for obfuscation and are not referenced anywhere

Comment: Also, before anyone suggests, deobfuscators like de4dot werent able to automatically do this

Comment: There are several thousands of unreferenced types and methods in the assembly, so removing them manually in dnSpy ins't an option

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was a noob mistake: you get this error when you delete a method that is used elsewhere in the assembly. When Cecil finds some other code trying to use that method, it fails to find it's implementation (because you deleted it), so it thinks it's a method from another assembly that just wasn't properly imported, and thus gives you this error.